# Route fails from one page, succeeds from another

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have one bit of javascript that fires off an ajax request, the result of which gets loaded into a popup dialog.

This is the same javascript in all cases, but in one case, the route fails.

From the new_army_list page:

```
Started POST "/army_lists/preview" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-10-13 21:42:15 -0400
Processing by ArmyListsController#preview as */*
```

From the edit_army_list page:

```
Started POST "/army_lists/preview" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-10-13 21:40:35 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/army_lists/preview"):


Rendered /home/bluepojo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.3ms)
```

The javascript in question:

```
function preview() {
  $.facebox(function() {
          var post_data = $('form').serialize();
          $.post('/army_lists/preview', post_data, function(data) {
                   $.facebox(data);
            });
        });
  }
```

Any idea what's going on? I can't figure out where to begin debugging this.

UPDATE:  Route:

```
preview_army_list POST   /army_lists/preview(.:format) {:controller=>"army_lists", :action=>"preview"}
```

UPDATE2:  Views

### application.html.haml

```
!!! XML
!!!
%head
  %title
    Skirmisher
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'screen'
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'facebox/facebox'
  = yield :stylesheets
  = javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'
  = javascript_include_tag 'facebox/facebox'
  = yield :javascripts
  = csrf_meta_tag
%body
  #wrapper
    #wrapper-top
      = yield

  = render :partial => 'shared/get_satisfaction_tab'
```

### edit.html.haml

```
= render :partial => 'form'
```

### new.html.haml

```
= render :partial => 'form'
```

### _form.html.haml

```
- content_for :javascripts do
  = javascript_include_tag 'new_list'

= form_for @army_list do |f|
  -if @army_list.errors.any?
    #errorExplanation
      %h2= "Fix #{pluralize(@army_list.errors.count, "error")} to save your list:"
      %ul
        - @army_list.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  .paper-super-wrapper
    .paper-wrapper
      = render :layout => 'shared/sidebar' do
        %li
          = f.submit 'Save', :id => 'save'
        %li.last
          %a{:href => '#', :title => 'Preview', :id => 'preview'}
            Preview
      = render :partial => 'floating_label', :locals => {:label => 'Title'}
    .paper-wrapper
      = render :layout => 'shared/paper' do
        = f.text_field :title, :class => 'list-input'
    .paper-wrapper
      = render :layout => 'floating_label', :locals => {:label => 'Army List'} do
        %li.first-common.last
          #new-section-button.button-div
            + Section
          #new-unit-button.button-div
            + Unit
      = render :layout => 'shared/paper' do
        = f.text_area :list, :class => 'list-input', :id => 'the-list'
      = render :partial => 'floating_label', :locals => {:label => 'Tags'}
    .paper-wrapper
      = render :layout => 'shared/paper' do
        = f.text_field :tag_list, :class => 'list-input'
```

Comment: Is there more than one form on that one page?

Comment: I double checked: there's only one form per page.

Comment: edit uses a PUT request. not POST. Aside form that, your question needs to include more information. Your routes and the form markup would be useful.

Comment: Also, your ajax call should use the form's `action` attribute instead of hard-coding it right into your javascript. Learn more about [unobtrusive javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript)

Comment: This is supposed to be a post, and it should not use the form's action, as I am not actually submitting the edit here. This is posting to a page that will generate a preview of the content entered into the form. Unobtrusive javascript is great, and I will try to follow those principles more, but I don't know if that's why my route is failing.  If you see the first half of my post, you'll see that the route succeeds when submitted from the new_army_list page, so it's not the javascript directly that is causing it to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was catching the `_method: put` parameter without realizing it, as I was serializing the form.

Fixed the issue by pulling the values out individually.